# Parsing XML that was received as an response in javascript,

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing

```
function parsingXML(APIResponse){ 
    var txt  = APIResponse.responseXML;
        if (window.DOMParser)
        {
        parser=new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
        }
        else // Internet Explorer
        {
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async=false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
        }
        console.log(APIResponse)
         console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SCID_WEB_REF_NUMBER")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

this is the error which was shown in the console

```
error TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
```

and the responseXML is :

```
"<NewDataSet>\r\n  <Table>\r\n    <SCID_WEB_REF_NUMBER>PIVP1005202112332381</SCID_WEB_REF_NUMBER>\r\n    <SCID_SBIL_SUPERVISOR_ID>O2026</SCID_SBIL_SUPERVISOR_ID>\r\n    <SCID_TYPE_OF_CLAIM>Sampoorna Suraksha</SCID_TYPE_OF_CLAIM>\r\n    <SCID_INVESTIGATION_TYPE>Document Procurement</SCID_INVESTIGATION_TYPE>\r\n    <SCID_POLICY_NUMBER>72112051821</SCID_POLICY_NUMBER>\r\n    <SCID_CUSTOMERID_EMPLOYEEID>50846</SCID_CUSTOMERID_EMPLOYEEID>\r\n    <SCID_CLAIMID>5082036</SCID_CLAIMID>\r\n    <SCID_UNIQUE_ID>72112051821|50846|5082036|</SCID_UNIQUE_ID>\r\n    <SCID_NAME_OF_LA>samay</SCID_NAME_OF_LA>\r\n    <SCID_DOB_OF_LA>1985-07-05T00:00:00+05:30</SCID_DOB_OF_LA>\r\n    <SCID_STATE_OF_LA>Delhi</SCID_STATE_OF_LA>\r\n    <SCID_INCOME_OF_LA>0</SCID_INCOME_OF_LA>\r\n    <SCID_PINCODE>0</SCID_PINCODE>\r\n    <SCID_DATE_OF_COMMENCEMENT>2019-12-08T00:00:00+05:30</SCID_DATE_OF_COMMENCEMENT>\r\n    <SCID_SUM_ASSURED>500000</SCID_SUM_ASSURED>\r\n    <DATE_OF_REVIVAL>0001-01-01T00:00:00+05:30</DATE_OF_REVIVAL>\r\n    <SCID_DATE_OF_DEATH>0001-01-01T00:00:00+05:30</SCID_DATE_OF_DEATH>\r\n    <SCID_NAME_OF_CLAIMANT>rahul</SCID_NAME_OF_CLAIMANT>\r\n    <SCID_CONTACT_NO_OF_CLAIMANT>9895123482</SCID_CONTACT_NO_OF_CLAIMANT>\r\n    <SCID_CONTACT_NUMBER_OF_LA>8975412327</SCID_CONTACT_NUMBER_OF_LA>\r\n    <SCID_STATUS>Inprogress</SCID_STATUS>\r\n    <SCID_CREATEDATE>2021-05-10T12:33:23+05:30</SCID_CREATEDATE>\r\n    <SCVID_VENDOR_SUPERVISOR_ID>VS4</SCVID_VENDOR_SUPERVISOR_ID>\r\n    <SCVID_VENDOR_INV_ID>VI1</SCVID_VENDOR_INV_ID>\r\n    <SCVID_EXPIRES_ON>2023-06-06T00:00:00+05:30</SCVID_EXPIRES_ON>\r\n    <SCVID_ASSIGNED_BY>VS4</SCVID_ASSIGNED_BY>\r\n    <SCVID_STATUS>AllocatedToInvestigator</SCVID_STATUS>\r\n    <ALLOCATION_DATE>2021-06-19T16:25:11+05:30</ALLOCATION_DATE>\r\n    <AGE>36</AGE>\r\n    <POLICYDURATION>-15</POLICYDURATION>\r\n  </Table>\r\n</NewDataSet>"
```

This is what is store in the APIResponse variable and passed into the parsingXML function

how do I parse this xml and get the data out of these xml tags, no matter what i tried, i was unable to figure it out.

the goal is to extract all the data from the xml response and store it in variables for futher processing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error message because your target node doesn't have any child nodes. Try this

```
target = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SCID_WEB_REF_NUMBER")
console.log(target[0].textContent)
```

The output should be:

```
"PIVP1005202112332381"
```